# Fluid simulation only renders surface leaving cavities against domain

Tags: fluid-simulation

The simulation runs fine, but only seems to add the mesh to the surface layer of the fluid. Any space between the surface and the domain that should be filled is left as a void. I tried changing the concavity numbers in the mesh settings, but that didn't do anything.

When I see other fluid simulation tutorials, there is no gap between the fluid and sides.

How do I fill the whole space with mesh that should be filled with the fluid?

[image]

Comment: could you share your file with me?  you can use this link:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the blend file anymore, and I've had no luck recreating this in either 2.83 or 2.91. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

After giving this a bounty because I had the same problem, I found the solution. When you simulate the fluid, the default settings only simulate the surface layer of the liquid. This is called a narrow band, which reduces memory and computational power needed. For some reason, the fluid mesher only meshes the narrow band.

**Scroll to the Liquid settings, and set narrow band to 0 to disable it.**

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question - since "normal" behaviour of Mantaflow doesn't generate a mesh with just the surface rendered as in the original post. Mantaflow normally concentrates fluid particles on the surface and the Narrow Band setting controls how thick that band should be. Presumably setting it to zero indicates that it shouldn't have a band and for particles to then be distributed through the entire fluid - which avoids the problem. I think it would be interesting to determine why the original poster got different results (was it a specific blender version with a bug?).

Comment: I'm with you Rich, the normal behaviour of Mantaflow should not mesh just the surface. I also tried to recreate the effect, and although it seems (from the screenshot) that all settings are left on default apart from the Diffuse values at 3.9 and 2, at frame 140 my fluid is less turbulent and the domain less filled. Since we can't see the flow object settings, I tried to give it a Z velocity of -30 m/s. It creates more turbulence and fills the domain, but still it meshes everything and not the surface. Also changing the narrow band doesn't produce the original poster's result.